# Javascript List group dropdown-menu Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" 
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
                         expanded="false">
                    Trier <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Par Nom</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Par Categorie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Par prix</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Par Défaut</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
            var show = $('.dropdown-menu li a ').text();
           alert(show);
        });

    });
</script>
```

I want to show in alert what I chose from the list. For example if I click on "Par Categorie" it will show me in alert "Par Catergorie" or anything related with this. PLEASE help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var show = $('.dropdown-menu li a ').text();`

To

`var show = $(this).text();`. This will give you the currently selected item from the dropdown.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
    var show = $(this).text();
    alert(show);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" 
    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
           expanded="false">
      Trier <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Par Nom</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Par Categorie</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Par prix</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Par Défaut</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @OmarKrichen, you are most welcome. Please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in if it helps...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok, the only problem is that in the event function you are selecting all the a elements, and you need to select only the one you click, like this

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(e) {
   var show = $(e.target).text();
   alert(show);
});
```

Note that I've added an argument "e" to the event function, that's the event, then I'm taking its target and using it as the selector.